# google analytic not showing real time data on specific Ip

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

Google Analytics not showing any result on specific IP, when check on mobile GA is showing the data. The error we are getting is "Resource is not available. Please try again later.
One or more of the services on which we depend is unavailable. Please try again later after the service has had a chance to recover."

Comment: It's a current error in GA. Apparently not related to set up.

Comment: This is an issue known by Google's engineers, and they are working on fixing it.

Comment: is it with all the accounts of Google Analytics ? or this is happening with random accounts at Random service stations ? @nyuen

Comment: It could have been all of them, at least for me it was. But for the most part, some of the accounts I was looking at last week are working now. I also read that a change was pushed out September 8, by engineering team.

Comment: Okay, Thank You @nyuen

Answer (score 1):

Google have a bug in Google Analytics, which they are trying to fix:
https://www.ohow.co/google-analytics-real-time-report-not-working-fix/

Comment: Thank you for the link Dennis, a great help!!